# How dynamically change ThemeProvider values in styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

In my projects I used some global css variables like --space-unit, --header-height and other.
And it looked like this :

```css
  --space-unit: 10px;
  --header-height: 70px;

  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    --space-unit: 7px;
    --header-height: 40px;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    --space-unit: 5px;
  }
```

And for different screen resolutions, the variables were appropriate. how do I implement this with styled-components? That is, I create ThemeProvider, enter the initial values of spaceUnit and headerHeight in it, but how do I dynamically change it later?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement your own way of updating the theme as ThemeProvider does not provide this functionality.

**You can use Context and wrap the existing ThemeProvider in your own provider that contains an updater function**:

```
const ThemeContext = createContext();
const ThemeContextProvider = props => {
   const [theme, setTheme] = useState(LIGHT_THEME);
   return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ setTheme, theme }}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              {props.children}
          </ThemeProvider>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

Then in your app:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <ThemeContextProvider>
            <SomeComponent/>
        </ThemeContextProvider>
    )
}

const SomeComponent = props => {
    const { setTheme, theme } = useContext(ThemeContextProvider);
    return <div>hello there</div>
}
```

Comment: I understand, thank you for the answer, I thought that there is already some ready-made solution for such situations. and frankly, it is very strange that it was not :( in this case, I will write something of my own